# Can't click button in webbrowser C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net

So basically I'm doing a project for my Degree (I do EEE, but the subject is on Machine Learning). I want to get a list of all the Reuters news articles using web browser through C#. Once I get the individual HREF links I would use HTML Agility Pack to extract the text of the individual articles and do some data-mining.

But for a search I make (https://www.reuters.com/search/news?blob=Trump&sortBy=date&dateRange=all), there are thousands of results displayed, and **I need to click on a "Load More Results" button on the page. I have tried certain methodologies found online, but it doesn't work! Any help would be appreciated!**

The button's HTML description is the following:

```
<div class="search-result-more">
        <div class="search-result-more-txt">LOAD MORE RESULTS</div>
        <div class="search-result-top"><a href="#top"></a></div>
</div>
```

And the code I've tried (after letting the webbrowser load the link) is:

```
            HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
            {
                if (link.GetAttribute("class").Equals("search-result-more-txt"))
                {
                    link.RaiseEvent("Click");
                }                  
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
      if (link.GetAttribute("className").Equals("search-result-more-txt"))
      {
          link.InvokeMember("Click");
      }
}
```